# A-frame position and size of camera and scene

Tags: camera, aframe, scene

I will like to put a label (or logo or menu or something else) at top of my "canvas" screen. This is my starting code:

https://codepen.io/alber-developer/pen/wvoezNY

As you will see, I have at top of page a span with "hello world!" text, it loads at first, but when the `<a-camera>` is loaded it positions at top of page and I don't see my `<span>` tag.

Here is a image example with what that I have (left one) and what I would to have (the right one):

[image: Left is bad - right is good]

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`<a-scene></a-scene>` takes up the entire screen, you might want to create a separate file with your a-scene and use an iframe to link to that file:

1st create a file containing your a-scene, as if you were to do a web page just for that a-scene. (code below)

```
  <head>
    <title>AR.js Basic Projected Camera Example</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    <!-- Look-at component. We don't need this now, but we will later. -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>  
          <a-camera rotation-reader  ></a-camera>
          <a-box rotation="20" position="0 0 -55"  material='color: blue' scale='10 10 10'></a-box>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

2nd create an iframe in your main whose src is the path to the file with the a-scene. (code below)

```
<head>
    <title>AR.js Basic Projected Camera Example</title>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    <!-- Look-at component. We don't need this now, but we will later. -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-look-at-component@0.8.0/dist/aframe-look-at-component.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div style="padding:10px; width:100%; height:200px; display: block; position: relative;">
        <span id="debug">HELLO WORLD!</span>
    </div>

    <iframe allowvr="yes" allowfullscreen="yes" src="the-path-to-your-file-with-your-aframe-scene"></iframe>

</body>
```